# Protractor export error - using classes from another project

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am trying to split my project into two separate projects and then reuse files between them.

At run time I get the following error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`  - `export {Helper} from './src/xx/hepler’;`

---

### main project

class-that-uses-the-helper-class.ts

```
import { Helper } from ‘sub-project’;
// const Helper = require (‘sub-project’);  also tried this
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "sub-project": "file:../../sub-project/e2e"
}
```

---

### sub-project

app.ts

```
 export {Helper} from './src/xx/helper’;
```

helper.ts

```
export class Helper {

}
```

package.json

```
 "name": "sub-project",

 "main": "app.ts"
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "lib",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "types": [
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use `import {Helper}` instead of `export {helper}` in your app.ts

Comment: If i change to `import`, i get `Helper is declared but its value is never read in app.ts`, and in main project test file `sub-project/app has no exported member Helper.ts`

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Typescript so apologies if I'm missing something obvious but am I correct in assuming you are using some of the functionality exported by `helper.ts` in the files where it is imported?

Comment: yes, thats correct

Comment: i seem to have solved the first error, by changing the import statement to use require: `import Helper = require('sub-project')`

Asked a new question here about the next error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297763/using-external-module-in-protractor-test-cannot-use-namespace-as-a-type

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't gotten more feedback on this question to be honest. I would have imagine this would be an easy solve for someone with good typescript knowledge but maybe I just don't know enough about typescript to properly understand it ha. Good luck anyway