# using external module in protractor test - cannot use namespace as a type

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am trying to split my project into two separate projects and then reuse files between them. Now that I am using my Helper class as an external module, I am getting errors trying to use it in my test. Am i importing/exporting the module incorrectly?

```
 - Cannot use namespace 'Helper' as a type
 - Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

> **main project**

test.ts

```
import Helper = require('sub-project');

describe(`Test Description`, () => {

    let helper: Helper; // error - cannot use namespace Helper as a type

    before(async () => {

        helper = new Helper(); // error - Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
        await helper.myFunction(xx, xx);

    });
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "sub-project": "file:../../sub-project/e2e"
}
```

> **sub-project**

app.ts

```
 export {Helper} from './src/xx/helper’;
```

helper.ts

```
export class Helper {

}
```

package.json

```
 "name": "sub-project",

 "main": "app.ts"
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "lib",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "types": [
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: `import Helper = require('sub-project');` why not `import { Helper } from './src/xx/helper';` ?

Comment: i thought it you are using something from `node_modules`, you should always use require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import Helper = require('sub-project');` is not the same as `import { Helper } from ...`. In helper file you're exporting class Helper with `Helper` name (not default, not absolute) so in test.ts file you should import it by `import { Helper } from '..'`

In case of `export default 42` you should use `import magicNumber from ...` (without {}).

Also you can find syntax like this 'import * as Lib from 'lib'`. It's used when someone is exporting all things by`module.exports = ...`. Don't use that if you don't need to

Also i suggest to don't use `require` syntax in TS files, `import` should better resolved types and also is more readable.